# How to order acronyms alphabetically in the acronyms table?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I am writing scientific research and I need to add the acronyms table, so I used the following commands:

```
\section*{List of Acronyms}  
\input{acro_list}
```

and listed the acronyms in the `acro_list` file as shown below:

```
\begin{acronym}[MPC] % Give the longest label here so that the list is nicely aligned
\acro{WSN}{Wireless Sensor Networks}
\acro{MPC}{model predictive control}
\acro{TLA}{Three Letter Acronym}
\end{acronym}
```

The following is an example that describes the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\section*{List of Acronyms}  
\input{acro_list}
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
First document \ac{MPC}.
\end{document}
```

The acronyms table mirrors the acronyms as written in the `acro-list` file which is unordered. So, the acronyms will be:

- WSN Wireless Sensor Networks
- MPC model predictive control
- TLA Three Letter Acronym

What I need is a way to display the acronyms alphabetically ordered in the acronyms table, but with keeping use of the `acro-list` file, as shown below:

- MPC model predictive control
- TLA Three Letter Acronym
- WSN Wireless Sensor Networks

Comment: Use a package, like `acro` or `glossaries`.
Also, please don't just post code snippets. Always try to create an MWE (minimal working example) that can be compiled as is.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your note. I will do this

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.